# How to add new member to Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I tried to add new member to GCP it gives me following error..?
Can we access GCP with Microsoft account..? Or how can we add Microsoft acc to GCP?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's the correct answer (and similar):

[Azure AD provisioning and SSO](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/identity/federating-gcp-with-azure-ad-configuring-provisioning-and-single-sign-on)

And there's a hacky (!?) **be very careful with this** answer:

[Google Account with a non-Google email address](https://accounts.google.com/signup/v2/webcreateaccount?flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=SignUp&nogm=true)

**Please do not even consider** the hacky answer unless this is a one-off and the Microsoft account is a personal account.

Google Cloud Platform only accepts Google accounts.

The federation mechanism creates proxy-like Google accounts for the Azure AD accounts and maintains the mapping for you.

The Google Account with a non-Google email address mechanism creates a Google Account (I strongly encourage you to also use a different password for the Google and Microsoft accounts even though they appear to be the same they are entirely different accounts).

If you use the hacky solution, it will create problems if you subsequently try the correct solution though Google Cloud Support may be able to help you delete the Google "shadow" account to help.

> **NOTE** Many years ago, the *only* way to use non-Google accounts with GCP was the hacky solution outlined above. Once the federation solutions became available, the hacky solution has become strongly discouraged.